# Spring TransactionTemplate doesn't handle exceptions

Tags: java, spring

When I try to catch `DataIntegrityViolationException` and convert it to my custom exception, catch block is not executed.

As an example I used code from this:
[guide](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate)

As a result, `ServicePointRepository` throws `DataIntegrityViolationException` that is handled at my controller layer, and the code during runtime seems to be avoiding catch block.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code from PersistenceService:

```
@Autowired
private ServicePointRepository servicePointRepository;

@Autowired
private BusinessExceptionFactory businessExceptionFactory;

@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

@Override
public String save(final ServicePointDTO servicePointDTO) {
    final ServicePointEntity servicePointEntity = mapToEntity(servicePointDTO);
    return transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
        try {
            return servicePointRepository.save(servicePointEntity).getId().toString();
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            throw businessExceptionFactory.createBusinessException(AlreadyExistException.class, CommonError.ALREADY_EXIST);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor post processor to proxy your repositories with logic to convert proprietary exception to Spring DataAccessException hierachy. Also remember to mark your repositories with the @Repository annotation for them to be detected and proxied

```
@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslatorPostProcessor(){
   return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
```

or equivalent in XML

Answer (score -1):

this is the correct method:

```
    @Override
public String save(final ServicePointDTO servicePointDTO) {
    final ServicePointEntity servicePointEntity = mapToEntity(servicePointDTO);
    try {
        return transactionTemplate.execute(status -> servicePointRepository.save(servicePointEntity).getId().toString());
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        throw businessExceptionFactory.createBusinessException(AlreadyExistException.class, CommonError.ALREADY_EXIST);
    }
}
```

also, this method should not be marked as `@Transactional`

Comment: @Transactional is used to ask Spring to handle the transaction for you. Not that it will bother if you're calling from the same class :(